# add tooltip to span tag with certain class on mousehover

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, angular

I have a html as a string in ts file. So I am displaying that in my html file. Some of the htmltext contains span tag with a class named highlight. What i want is that when I hover my mouse over the highlight class I have to get a tooltip.

This is my string or **text** in the ts file. It is stored in variable named text

```
'<span class="highlight">It is a long</span> established fact that a <span ​lass="highlight">re</span><span class="highlight"></span><span class="highlight">ader </span>will be distracted by the <span class="highlight">readable content </span>of a page when <span class="highlight">look</span><span class="highlight"></span><span class="highlight">ing </span>at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum'
```

I have attached my stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2dbum9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: This is pseduo code but something like add hover ever and append a new element to it.

:
"const handleHover = (e) => { 
  const tooltip = createElement('div')
  e.target.value.append(tooltip)
}

<div [innerHtml]="text" onHover={(e)=> handleHover(e)}>
  {{text}}
</div>
"

Comment: can you please show it on stackblitz? @ColinRosati

Comment: What will you show on that tooltip?

Comment: Maybe just add a `title` attribute with text to each element you want show tooltip for?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `title` attribute to each `highlight` element to display a tooltip.

Here is an example where first `highlight` element has a static tooltip and the rest of them generated dynamically (see main.ts):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qqncae

Also you need `ViewEncapsulation` in order to use external .css

```
import { Component, VERSION, ViewEncapsulation } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
```

Comment: Can you pls add the main.ts code in appcomponent ts itself? @vanowm

Comment: which line of code did you add the dynamically generated tooltip date?